# How to reduce the click area of an Button?

Tags: java, android, android-button, android-gridview

I have a gridview that is filled with buttons that looks like this:

[image]

right now if I click anywhere on the button, it will be pressed. But I want to the button to only be pressed when it's clicked in the light gray area, not the dark gray or white area on the top and left sides. I tried using `setPadding(int,int,int,int)` and `setPaddingRelative(int,int,int,int)` but neither of them makes any effect. How do I fix this?

Edit: the button is 50x50 and is already extended from the Button Class

Comment: You **could** put the Button inside a layout. The Layout would make the "borders" and the Button will be the grey area only (so to be the only **reactive area**). EASY. DONE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override onTouchEvent in your custom button:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (isInGrayArea(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
       return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    return false;
}
```

event.getX() and event.getY() is pixels coordinates, you will need to convert them into dp, I suppose.

Comment: please share isInGrayArea function

Answer (score 1):

Make a custom Button view inherit from Button class and override onDraw method with custom code to do that.

You can override touch methods to detect when button is pressed and get the x and y coords to remove cases when button must not be pressed.

Comment: What custom code in onDraw won't make the button click on certain coordinates?